# Is .fail() or .timeout() better in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

I need to handle timeouts on my $.ajax() calls for a jQueryMobile project. Doing some research I've come across two viable methods of doing this.

<strike>`.error()`</strike> `.fail()` seems to be generic: if the call fails for any reason then i'm kicked back an error stack, and then the function call is written to handle whatever I need it to.

`.timeout`, seems to let me deal specifically with timeouts and specify a time period that I can wait, if i don't receive an answer, then the call times out and throws an error.

My question is in a mobile environment, would it be better to handle timeouts with the `.timeout()` call? Or should I blanket all calls with the <strike>`.error()`</strike> `.fail()` function and handle timeouts within the error callback?

Working with mobile devices it is expected that a user may walk out of a coverage zone, so if the call never returns, my gut would say to implement a timeout function. Do error callbacks have a built in timeout? I would like to handle all errors gracefully, so it seems that maybe a happy medium would be implementing both, and specifying timeouts to work directly with the timeout callback.

Is there anything I might be missing here?

Comment: Just a note, `.error` is depreciated, use `.fail`

Comment: I would suggest using the timeout option in addition to adding a `fail` handler.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax mentions it, but it is also explained in the deferred object documentation at http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: Actually, this still presents the same question. I've read the docs, and i guess my question is more which is better, or is it expected that i would use .timeout() to handle only time outs. I want to know if .fail() has a built in mechanism for handling timeouts or not

Comment: I've never heard of a `.timeout()` method. What are you referring to?

Comment: It appears that i was looking at the designation wrong, i guess timeout is simply an option that you specify, and then an error is thrown if the time is exceeded. I assume fail would catch this?

Comment: Yes, `.fail()` callback(s) will be executed if the timeout is exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The timeout-event will trigger the `fail()`-function!**

You should set a timeout-value for the `$.ajax()`-request.

```
$.ajax({
     timeout: 15000 // 15sec
    });
```

If the ajax-request hasn't recieved a response in this period of time it will excecute the function that has been passed in the `.fail()`-function.

```
$.ajax()
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        if(textStatus === 'timeout') {
             alert("$.ajax failed!"); 
        {
  });
```